# Protocol and design resource of 3.5mm stereo jack remote control

Tags: infrared, stereo

I've seen a few audio visual equipments that can be controlled with both wired (3.5mm stereo jack) and wireless (infrared). On the equipments, there are IR receiver port and also a port that resemble audio in port used for wired remote control.

On the remote control side, it also has both IR transmitter and 3.5mm port.

I have no problem deciphering and emulating the infrared code that the infrared remote generates but I am wondering how does the 3.5mm jack control works. Is there any standard or protocol for this or does each manufacturer creates their own?

How do I capture the stuff sent from 3.5mm port of the remote control to the equients? Any idea?

Comment: I'd make a wild guess that the wired communication protocol is the same as the IR one - then the manufacturer wouldn't have to deal with two communication protocols.

Comment: What are the make(s) and model(s) of the audio equipment in question? Sony used to (may still) use the [LANC protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LANC) for device control, which sometimes used a 2.5mm stereo jack.

Comment: I think you are right, Peter!I saw one post that confirm your guess : http://wiredremotecontrol.blogspot.sg/2005/10/pioneer-sr-control-inout-jacks-there.html?m=1

Comment: Hi Markt, it's an Onkyo TX-NR807.

Answer (score 1):

For capturing the signal you need an oscilloscope or logic analyzer. The easiest thing that comes to mind is a [Bus Pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate) used as a logic analyzer. They are pretty cheap and useful for lots of things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Austin! Will look into it although I have never used one before.